# Getting this error PageViewController does not conform to protocol 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am not able to fix this error or find out the cause of this error and error is shown in below screenshot.

Simply trying to create a demo of pageViewController and i am not able to add dataSource class, and that self.dataSource = self.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding the protocol definition for your custom class is not enough. You have to provide at least the two required functions of the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```